# Subscribe to a nested observable

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, rxjs

Let's say I have a function in a **provider**:

```
saveCar(car: Car) {
    return this.saveCarImages(car).subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        if(data[0].seats){
          car=data[0];
      }
      return this.api.put(`/car/${car.id}`, car, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      }
    )
  }
```

And this helper function in the **provider** that has to be executed before the actual car is saved:

```
 saveCarImages(car: Car) {
    return Observable.create((observable) => {
      let fileSaver = this.injector.get(FileSaverProvider);
    let promisearr = [];
        promisearr.push(Observable.create((observable) => {
          fileSaver.uploadImage(car.helpImage.file).subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              car.helpImageId = data.id;
              observable.complete(car);
            }
          )
        })
        )
            promisearr.push(Observable.create((observable) => {
              fileSaver.uploadImage(car.helpImage2.file).subscribe(
                (data: any) => {
                  car.helpImageId2 = data.id;
                  observable.complete(car);
                }
              )
              }));
    return Observable.forkJoin(promisearr);
    });
  }
```

And then I have this code in a **TS file of a component**:

```
        this.provider.saveCar(this.car).subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                if (response) {
                       //success
                }
            },
            (error: any) => {
                      //error
            }
        );
```

But this is not working. What Im trying to achieve here is subscribing to this.api.put(car) from the TS file of the component, but I need the car images to be uploaded first, therefore the this.api.put(car) is nested inside the saveImages observable. How can I subscribe to the this.api.put(car) from the TS file of the component?

Comment: This has got to be the #1 question on RxJS. What you need is the `mergeMap` operator. Please refer to this explanation: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html and for the implementaion: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `Observable.create` method. That is a pretty low level way to create Observables, which you normally do not need to use.

Specifically, looking at you code, you could look if this version of the helper method works

```
saveCarImages(car: Car) {
    const fileSaver = this.injector.get(FileSaverProvider);
    const obsArray = [];
    obsArray.push(fileSaver.uploadImage(car.helpImage.file).pipe(map(id => {
       car.helpImageId = id;
       return car;
    })));
    obsArray.push(fileSaver.uploadImage(car.helpImage2.file).pipe(map(id => {
       car.helpImageId2 = id;
       return car
    })));
    return forkJoin(obsArray);
  }
```

Then `saveCar` would become

```
saveCar(car: Car) {
   return this.saveCarImages(car).pipe(
     map(data => data[0]),
     switchMap(car => this.api.put(`/car/${car.id}`, car, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

At this point your component should be able to call `saveCar` and subscribe to it.